# average method arrays hint

Tags: java, arrays

Can you give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong with my average in the average method? I'm trying to call the method in the read scores.I'm trying to get the average of the scores I have in my input.txt file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class FindGrade {
public static final int NUM_SCORE_TYPES = 5;   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = null;
    int[] quizArray = null;    
    int[] labArray = null;     
    int[] attendance = null; 
    int[] midterms = null; 
    int quizgrade =0;
    int labgrade=0;
    int attendance_1=0;
    int midterms_1 =0;
    String name;


    try {
        scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt")); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    // each iteration is for single exam type (ie: Quizzes is the 1st one)
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SCORE_TYPES; i++) {

        name = scan.next(); 
        int numScores = scan.nextInt();
        int maxGrade = scan.nextInt();

        if (name.equals("Quizzes")) {
            quizArray = new int[numScores];
            readScores(quizArray, numScores, scan);


        }

        else if (name.equals("Labs")) {
            labArray = new int[numScores];
            readScores(labArray, numScores, scan);

        }
        else if (name.equals("Lab_attendance")) {
            attendance = new int[numScores];
            readScores(attendance, numScores, scan);

        }
        else if (name.equals("Midterms")) {
            midterms = new int[numScores];
            readScores(midterms, numScores, scan);

        }

    }

}


public static void readScores(int[] scoreArray, int numScores, Scanner scan) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numScores; i++) { 
        scoreArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
}

public static void average(double [] scoreArray, int numScores){
    double sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i< scoreArray.length; i++){
        sum += scoreArray[i];
    }
    double average = sum/numScores;

    System.out.println(sum + " " + average);



}
```

Comment: What's the stacktrace you get?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner I'm not familiar with the term stacktrace.

Comment: What is the error you get? (Stacktrace is the error log that Java provides, basically.

Comment: I'm not getting an error just nothing is printing out for me

Comment: You never call `average`...

Comment: When I do call average the error I get is "average cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: I called it in readScores

Comment: What specific code did you use?

Answer (score 1):

In any case, you can't directly call it with the arrays that you are creating there. Because the arrays are of type `int`, but the average-method requires a `double` array. When you change this, you can call the method like this...

```
public static void readScores(int[] scoreArray, int numScores, Scanner scan) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numScores; i++) { 
        scoreArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }

    average(scoreArray, numScores); // <----- Call it here
}

public static void average(int[] scoreArray, int numScores){
    double sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i< scoreArray.length; i++){
        sum += scoreArray[i];
    }
    double average = sum/numScores;
    System.out.println(sum + " " + average);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it